# Why does string change to integer when VBA calls Python method?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm just getting started with xlwings and Python and I'm running into something I don't understand.

I use `xlwingsings quickstart someProject` to get started. This creates a workbook with a macro called SampleCall that points to Module1. I add a string to Module1 and passed it to the main Python method like this:

```
Sub SampleCall()
Dim someString As String
someString = "2-1"
mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
RunPython ("import " & my module & ";" & mymodule & ".main(" & someString & ")")
```

Then I adjust the autogenerated Python script to verify that my string is still a string:

```
import xlwings as xw
@xw.sub
def main(someString):
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    sheet = wb.sheet[0]
    sheet["A1"].value = str(type(someString))
```

This writes `<class 'int'>` to my spreadsheet, when I expected it to report a string. Where and why is my string changing to an integer?

Comment: you create `main(2-1)` but for python interpreter it is always number - you may have to use `\"` to add `" "` and create string - `main("2-1")`

Comment: BTW: you could create `text = "import " & my module & ";" & mymodule & ".main(" & someString & ")"` and display it - to see what you send to Python Interpreter.

Comment: @furas: You are right, I had to quote the string. Thank you.